Abs of complex numbers in Wolfram Mathematica
How to get abs of complex numbers in Wolfram Mathematica? If you do like ComplexExpand[Abs[num]], it doesn't work, for example, for num = ArcSin[a] + I b. If you write Assumptions in Mathematica, it is ignored and gives complicated expressions for Abs[num].

What do you think the output should be?

Clear[a, b]

num = ArcSin[a] + I*b
(* I b + ArcSin[a] *)

Abs[num]
(* Abs[I b + ArcSin[a]] *)

a = 3; b = 4;

num = ArcSin[a] + I*b
(* 4 I + ArcSin[3] *)

Abs[num]
(* Sqrt[(4 + Im[ArcSin[3]])^2 + Re[ArcSin[3]]^2] *)

% // N
(* 2.73362 *)


One way is:
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[ArcSin[a] + I b], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals]

(*Piecewise[{{Sqrt[b^2 + ArcTan[Sqrt[1 - a^2], a]^2], -1 < a < 1}}, Indeterminate]*)

